# How HTTP 1.1 and HTTP 2.0 works in Spring Boot?

Tags: https, http, springboot, springframework

What are the differences in flow changes for HTTP 1.1 and HTTP 2.0 for Spring Boot applications ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP/1 was known to have poor response time. With websites becoming more resource-intensive, the protocol was losing its efficiency. It progressively became essential to minimize latency and boost page load speeds

**HTTP/1.1**

The client has to send a request to the server using the method (GET/POST).
Server responds with the requested resource, for example – html page or image or css resource, alongside the status of what it did to the client’s request.
So this is not one time process. Such requests and responses needs to be transferred between both these machines until the client receives all the resources, essential to load a web page on the end-user’s till that time only one connection will be open for one request and this is limitation, client has to wait for another request to server until first one complete.

**HTTP/2**

HTTP/2 was an attempt to overcome the limitations of HTTP/1.1 and make it a more efficient web protocol.

Considering the bottleneck in the previous scenario(HTTP/1.1), the HTTP/2 introduced a binary framing layer. This layer partitions requests and responses in tiny data packets and encodes them with multiplexed streams level. Due to this, multiple requests and responses become able to run parallelly with HTTP/2